# C++: Daemon to detect USB dongle

Tags: c++, linux, daemon, gnu

I have dongle with specific USB UUID (or whatever else it's called).

I want to set up event when USB device is connected and if the UUID will be right it will unlock protected directory.

I have code how to unlock the directory, but I don't know how to check device UUID and how to set up event described above.

**EDIT:** It's app for GNU/Linux.

Comment: I've found this: http://linux.die.net/man/5/hotswaprc (but I don't like scripting idea, is there any way to do it with daemon?)

Comment: BTW. I don't have hotswap in my distro and it isn't present in repos.

Comment: The `udev` daemon is already running.  Why do you want a second daemon consuming system resources continually and doing the exact same thing as an existing service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the source code for the `udev` daemon.  Or you could just let `udev` do what it's already designed to do, and plug your logic in as a `udev`-triggered hotswap script.

Comment: Thanks, I think I don't need daemon.